# Most efficient way to create a frame for eye glasses?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

How would you make a frame for eye glasses? More specifically, the part that sticks out over the ears.

I'm looking into curves and deforming a cube to do this, or possibly just beveling a curve into what I want. What would be the easiest and best way to create this shape?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the fastest way would be to use beveled curve. Here's a simple one using only curve with a **Mirror** modifier:

[image: 1a]

Cyclic property of the curve splines that form each lenses' rim is toggled on, and the frame's width can be varied by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> on selected control point. To some extent, the frame's shape can be further modified by using *taper* and *bevel* object:

[image: 2a]

Note that both objects affect the appearance of all splines within the curve. Modifying just part of the curve will require that part to be separated as a new curve object.

## Handle Part

Modeling the glasses' handle can be done manually as the others' answers, or by using a **Curve** modifier on the handle's mesh object:

[image: 3a]

You may get lesser control than by shaping it manually. But using this method, you can quickly adjust the handle's curvature by editing the curve, editing the mesh itself mostly to control the shape along its length:

[image: 4a]

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a plane, scale it to a rectangle;
2. Select one side edge in Edit Mode, Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then click <kbd>LMB</kbd> somewhere to extrude the low end of the final stick;
3. Add a few support loops by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>;
4. Add a **Solidify** modifier (to make the thickness), then and a **Subsurf** modifier (to subdivide);
5. Scale the edge(s) on the lower end until satisfied.

**P.S.**: You can adjust the thickness and subdivision level in the modifier stack as you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, curves is probably the way to go. However here is a simple way you can model this:

1. Add a Circle (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*>Mesh > Circle*) and delete (<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>) most of it:

   [image]
2. Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) one vertex out:

   [image]
3. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) sideways:

   [image]
4. Add a solidify modifier and a subsurf modifier:

   [image]